# Which of these is the more correct implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I've wondered often about this: Which of the following two implementations of `INotifyPropertyChanged` for any property `Foo` is the better, or even more correct one?

```
/* version A: */                      |     /* version B: */
private bool foo;                     |     private bool foo;
public bool Foo                       |     public bool Foo
{                                     |     {
   set                                |        set
   {                                  |        {
                                      |           if (value != foo)
                                      |           {
      foo = value;                    |              foo = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Foo");       |              OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
                                      |           }
    }                                 |        }
}                                     |     }
```

(I've omitted everything that is not relevant for this question.)

I suspect it should be version B on the right, as it prevents unnecessary events from being triggered. However, are there situations where these very same, missed events could lead to problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version B looks more correct as it doesn't raise the event if the property hasn't actually changed value. There won't be any problems with Version A, it's just an unnecessary call which won't update any of the UI.

And as the [documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx):

> Notifies clients that a property value
>   has changed.

Comment: What do you think, could B potentially lead to an issue, namely where a subscriber expects the event to be triggered each time the property is *written to* (as opposed to *changed in value*)?

Comment: @stakx, I can't think of such situation. The interface is called INotifyPropertyChanged and not INotifyPropertyValueWasWritten, so subscribers should expect to be notified only if the value actually changed.

Comment: a very reasonable point, that. It's just that I hardly ever see that interface implemented like version B, but instead mostly like version A. Maybe that's due to laziness? If noone comes up with a defense of version A, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: The only situation I could envision version A being useful would be for debugging, finding out exactly when by what the property setter is accessed.